# How to send data from struts2 to a javascript function to draw a chart

Tags: java, javascript, charts, struts2, chart.js

I need to add a dynamic chart into a webapp of mine.
I have choosen chartjs as library (for the line charts)
After the creation of the page with the chart inside and the definition of the action that retrieves data from database I am experiencing some problems sending data from the action to the script that generates the line chart.

The servlet gives as output an ArrayList of Beans

```
@Action(value="/graphDataFetcher")
public String execute(){
    //Connessione a database 
    DBUtility database= new DBUtility(); 
    Connection connessione=database.getConnected();
    listamusei=database.getMusei(connessione);
    //Recupero in liste di musei e mostre correlate
    for(Museo ms: listamusei){
        mostre=new ArrayList<Mostra>();
        mostre=database.getMostraInMuseo(String.valueOf(ms.getId()), connessione);
        ms.setMostre(mostre);
    }
    //Disconnessione da database
    database.getDisconnected();
    return "ok";
}
```

This is the scripts that "rules" the chart, I want to set the bean's attributes as value1, value2 , value3.. and so on.

```
<script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [value1, value2, value3, value4]
         },
         ]
    }
    window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true
    });
}
</script>
```

Does someone have some idea about how to fix this?

Comment: So you have List<Museo> containing List<Mostra>... what exactly do you want to print as "value1, value, etc" ? Side note: that is an Action, not a servlet (quite different)

Answer (score 1):

you can use by two ways
1. take a list in action with setter, getter and add data in this list. In jsp page use strcts tag library and in javascript variable put list data. Then call chartjs library function with data like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = new Array();
<s:iterator var="newsVar" value="newsList" status="newsStatus">
a[<s:property value="#newsStatus.index"/>]='<s:property value="id"/>';
</s:iterator>
$(document).ready(function(){
 chartjsfunction(a);
});
</script>
```

2. send ajax call for data to action and send data to chartjs library function.

Comment: This is the dirty way, he could use JSON for that, is very easy.

Comment: JSON is okey if we use ajax call for data.